# Accessing AWS service from a program calling aws cli

Tags: linux, go, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Running EC2 instance that has an IAM role attached that allows to copy/read files to/from an S3 bucket.

When logged into the EC2 instance (via ssh) I can perform all those tasks using `aws s3 ...` command. There are no credentials because it's using a role. Env does not have anything related to aws at all.
However, if I run a program (written in GO) that simply does:

```
exec.Command("bash", "-c", "aws s3 ls ....")
```

I get `Partial credentials found in env, missing: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

A bit confused here, shouldn't it just work since I'm running this process as the same user that I'm logged in as and that actually works as I've mentioned in the beginning? Why is it even looking for credentials?

Comment: Programs that use the AWS SDK (including the AWS CLI) look for the credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`, which means it looks inside the current user's home directory. Perhaps when running the AWS CLI with `exec.Command()`, it is not actually running "as" the same user? Perhaps you can try running `exec.Command("bash", "-c", "whoami")` and `exec.Command("bash", "-c", "echo $HOME")` to find out?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, both "whoami" and "echo $HOME" output the same user as I'm using to ssh in. Another note, this user does not even have ~/.aws/credentials file and when I ssh in and run "aws configure list" it outputs: 
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************Z4TY         iam-role
secret_key     ****************+8np         iam-role
which means it auto generates a temp secret key somehow on login

Comment: Certainly seems strange! You might need to use the [AWS SDK for Go](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/) rather than calling the AWS CLI as a sub-command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, assuming you have a role (lets call it EC2S3AccessRole) that allows ec2 instance access to s3 bucket(s), you need to follow this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

Eg, in my case (golang), I would do something like this:

a. get token:

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", `curl -X PUT http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 600"`)
```

b. get credentials using token from (a)

```
type IAMSecurityCreds struct {
Code            string    `json:"Code"`
LastUpdated     time.Time `json:"LastUpdated"`
Type            string    `json:"Type"`
AccessKeyID     string    `json:"AccessKeyId"`
SecretAccessKey string    `json:"SecretAccessKey"`
Token           string    `json:"Token"`
Expiration      time.Time `json:"Expiration"`
}
...

cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", `curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: `+token+`" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/EC2S3AccessRole`)
...
json.Unmarshal into IAMSecurityCreds
```

c. once you have all three (token, key, secret), you can run something like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=` + creds.AccessKeyID + ` AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=` + creds.SecretAccessKey + ` AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="` + creds.Token + `" aws s3 ........`)
```

That's it :)